# kernel panic при выключении

Tags: linux

kernel panic not syncing timeout not all cpus entered broadcast exception handler
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Убедитесь что у вас последняя версия BIOS. Скорее всего дело в этом.
2. Убедитесь что у вас последний микрокод.

Для последнего вам нужен такой пакет:

```
apt install intel-microcode
```

Проверть что микрокод загрузился можно так:

```
dmesg | grep microcode
```

Должно вывести что-то вроде:

```
CPU0 microcode updated early to ...
```

Наконец, можно попробовать отключить Intel SpeedStep, обновить ядро и реже выключаться.

Comment: `alexey@ferma1:~$ sudo apt-get install intel-microcode 
[sudo] пароль для alexey: 
  iucode-tool
НОВЫЕ пакеты, которые будут установлены:
  intel-microcode iucode-tool
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] y
intel-microcode: microcode will be updated at next boot
Обрабатываются триггеры для initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) …
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-54-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
alexey@ferma1:~$ dmesg | grep microcode
[    2.128268] microcode: sig=0x306c3, pf=0x2, revision=0x9
[    2.153051] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.01 `

Comment: SpeedStep выключил!